# Join with no Condition on MS-Access (Unconditional Join)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Suppose I have two tables:

```
ColX      ColY
--------  --------
Jim       26
Jake      5
Anastase  64

ColA      ColB
--------  --------
55523265  true
29874902  false
90387546  true
```

I would like to Join them into one table as follows:

```
ColX      ColB
--------  --------
Jim       true
Jake      false
Anastase  true
```

I tried creating a query as follows:

```
Select T1.ColX, S2.Mark FROM S1
INNER JOIN S2 ON 1=1
```

But MS-Access doesn't like that. It says that Join Statement is not Supported.
Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Edit: It is probably worth noting  two things:

1. This is a deliberate attempt at an Inference attack for a security course.
2. MS-Access does not have a rownumber() function.

Comment: Sounds dangerous. But if they are literally perfectly (and always) aligned by row, you could add a row id and join on that, perhaps?

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can add a rowID to my query? I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Actually what that query is doing is essentially a cross join. Every row in S1 will have a matching row from S2. So is you have 5 rows in each table the result should be 25 rows. Your design is flawed. You need something in S2 to know which row(s) it belongs to from S1. If you have created a 1:1 relationship why did you even bother with a second table?

Comment: If this is a one off and you know the alignment is perfect and always will be, you can run this on each: `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN row_id COUNTER`. But your join will only work if the order / alignment *happens* to be perfect. Beware.

Comment: @ako: Perfect. It was so difficult to find that particular command.  Please post as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dangerous territory and is not a good general solution. But if this is a one off and you know the alignment between the two tables happens to be is perfect (like, if you literally pasted columns together in Excel that you could visually inspect for alignment), you can run this on each:

`ALTER TABLE mytable1 ADD COLUMN row_id COUNTER`

`ALTER TABLE mytable2 ADD COLUMN row_id COUNTER`

and then join on `row_id`.

But your join will only work if the order / alignment happens to be perfect. Beware.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have *something* that relates one table to another.  You can't count on row position.  You can add a column with a sequential number and join on that, but otherwise what you're asking makes no sense.

Comment: Let me make a physical analogy.  People (at least in the US) have a SSN.  Cars have a VIN.  What you're asking is like having a room full of people and a parking lot full of cars with no further information and winding up with John in the Red Buick.